# how we perform scroll in table

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to perform scroll down in web table but its not performing with a logic

```
JavascriptExecutor jse1 = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jse1.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,200)");
```

Comment: What error did u got? Can you attach HTML and error log.

Comment: @sandeepkumar their is no error coming in console

Comment: Give you give us HTML code of the page along with table?

Comment: sorry @santhoshkumar i am not getting your point

Comment: can u try this and let me know `WebElement tableElement= driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath to table"));

JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)", tableElement);`

Comment: @Tuks recently i tried this but its failed for me

Comment: can to share the site URL ?

Comment: Sorry @tuks its working only on local machine

Comment: Please share the HTML for the table element

Answer (score 1):

Use `EventFiringWebDriver`.

Steps:

1. Launch the Web Application.
2. Locate the `WebTable`.
3. Use `executeScript`.

Below is the code:

```
eventFiringWebDriver eventFiringWebDriver = new EventFiringWebDriver(driver);
eventFiringWebDriver.executeScript("document.querySelector('.ui-grid-viewport.ng-isolate-scope').scrollTop=6000");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Selenium's [Actions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html) class.

**Steps:**

Create your WebDriver instance

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Create your Actions instance by passing the driver instance as parameter.

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver)
```

Locate your element (table you want to scroll to)

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("tableXpath"));
```

Move to the element

```
actions.moveToElement(element).perform();
```